# Form for has_many :trough association with creating object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

### Problem

With my rails app I'm trying to accomplish something like image below.

[image]

*Invoice* should has many *Items*. For example Invoice_1 would have in *invoice_items* container: 
`[{item: Egg, quantity: 3, unit_price: 4}, {item: Stick, quantity: 4, unit_price: 2}]`.

How to made a form to add *n* *Items* to *Invoice*?

Or how to edit this form/controller to create fixed number of *InvoiceItems* for a start. Later I'll figure how to create *Items* and create associations dynamically in html.

### Source

#### Models

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoice_items
  has_many :invoices, through: :invoice_items
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoice_items, inverse_of: :invoice
  has_many :items, through: :invoice_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_items

  validates :items, :length => { :minimum => 1 }
end

class InvoiceItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :item

  validates_presence_of :invoice
  validates_presence_of :item

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item
end
```

#### Invoice controller

```
# GET /invoices/new
def new
  @invoice = Invoice.new
  @invoice.invoice_items.build
end

private: 
def invoice_params
  #params.fetch(:invoice, {})
  params.require(:invoice).permit(
  :date,
  :seller_id,
  :client_id,
  invoice_items_attributes: [ item_attributes:
    [:name, :quantity, :unit, :unit_price_cents, :unit_price_currency, :price_cents, :price_currency ]
    ],
  invoice_name_attributes: [:number, :month, :year],
  )
end
```

#### Invoice form

```
<%= form_for(@invoice) do |invoice_form| %>
  <%= invoice_form.fields_for :invoice_items do |invoice_item_form| %>
    <%= invoice_item_form.fields_for :item do |item_form| %>
      <%= item_form.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= invoice_form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I'm reading, you probably just want to focus on making InvoiceItem records built from an invoice. You can build a fixed number (n) of invoice items by using code such as n.times { invoice.invoice_items.build } in the new method in your controller.

When you want to create dynamic fields there is a gem called Cocoon which allows you to dynamically add associated records to a form.

My advice is just to use fields_for :invoice_items as you have done already in your form and omit the fields_for :items. Instead in the invoice_items form add a select_tag that includes all of the Items you want to add to an invoice.